# php shorthand issue

Tags: php, shorthand

I have this:

```
$color = $status == 1 || $status == 2 ? 'read' : 'unread' || $status == 3 ? 'delete' : 'unread';
```

However it's wrong.  If the `$status` isn't 3--it still returns 'delete'

What is wrong? Should I use a `else if` instead of shorthand for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What are you trying to get for your result?  I'm assuming you want:

1. read
2. unread
3. delete
4. unread

   $color = ($status == 1) ? 'read' :
             ($status == 3) ? 'delete' :
             'unread'

(which is, for some reason, not showing my line breaks)

For readability, however, I'd use either `if/else` or `switch`:

```
switch ($status) {
    case 1: $color = 'read'; break;
    case 3: $color = 'delete'; break;
    default: $color = 'unread';
}
```

Generally, I don't use the '?:' form unless I will gain a HUGE improvement; usually, more readable is better.

Comment: I've actually never used a switch in PHP yet.  I will take back what I said about my answer `$color = $status == 1 || $status == 2 ? 'read' : ('unread' || $status == 3 ? 'delete' : 'unread');` and move into a switch because your right.

Answer (score 3):

1) || not 100% equal to OR such as && not 100% equal to AND

2) Use brackets

P.S.: yes, use "if .. else" - it will increase code readability.

Comment: Sure: && and || has higher priority than AND and OR. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.php#43111

Answer (score 1):

I would say not to do this as shorthand - longhand will be easier to read, both for you in three days time when you've forgotten what you were doing, or when someone else comes along.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator has a wacky binding.

And you could be using a map instead:

```
$map = array(0=>"unread", 1=>"unread", 2=>"read", 3=>"delete");

$color = $map[ min(3,$status) ];   // min is actually the max value here
```

Comment: your array $map: what does it mean if "unread" just sits by itself?

Comment: @Kyle: Ah sorry. The first entry occupies the `[0]` index. It's another fallback. If you are sure that $status cannot be zero, then you could leave it out. In other cases it's best to note all potential values. I would leave out all `123=>` specifiers and make it just a list. OTOH it's more readable to list them exactly. -- If $status is certainly between 0 and 3, then you can also leave out the `min()` hack, making this even more terse than the switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed with parenthesis thanks Chvanikoff.

```
$color = ($status == 1 || $status == 2) ? 'read' : ('unread' || $status == 3 ? 'delete' : '');
```